# Given a large 2D matrix, how many 2D matrix of smaller size n can I uniquely fit?

Tags: c++, math, matrix

I have a large 2D Matrix that represents a 3D Games' 2D terrain - Walls and Floors of various types (dirt, rock, etc).
Lets for example say there is an area of 4x9 of rock floor. I have a requirement to place an object at the center of every 3x3 area of the 4x9 space, and an object to place at every 1x1 area after resolving and excluding the 3x3 areas.

The result should be 3 objects placed of the 3x3 template and 9 objects placed of the 1x1 template.

What would be the most efficient way to implement this algorithm?

Comment: Is this a 2D version of "make-change"?

Comment: @BobMurphy: To be honest I'm at a loss as to where to really start. In my head I'm thinking I need another matrix to use to mark units off as 'used' when I make them part of, for example, a 3x3 template. But it feels messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `canPlace` be a BST of coordinates.

```
for (x = 0:w)
for (y = 0:h)
  shouldPlace = true
  for (x2 = -1:1)
  for (y2 = -1:1)
    if (grid[x+x2][y+y2].isObstruction())
      shouldPlace = false
  if (shouldPlace)
    canPlace.add((x,y))
```

The above complexity is `O(n^2 log n)`

Recursively try all `canPlace` positions to place 3x3 objects.

When you are doing this, mark the area where you're placing it as obstructed, and check for obstructed before placing.

Above complexity = ? (more possible placings allows us to find a solution very quickly)

```
for (x = 0:w)
for (y = 0:h)
  if (grid[x][y].isEmpty())
    place1x1(x, y)
```

Above complexity = `O(n^2)`

Total complexity = `O(n^2 log n + ?)`

Comment: Won't this attempt to place 2 3x3 templates within for example a 3x4 area as its not excluding now used xy units from the first 3x3 template placed down?
Or have you simply not shown that here?